# How to measure the execution speed of launch::async?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, concurrent.futures

I'm working on my assignment and trying to measure the execution speed on the `async` policy.
The time I get without iterating the `raNums` vector is about 60 seconds, which is quite a lot. And with its iteration - 9 milliseconds, which is quite a bit (I understand that in this case, processes are going without stop). However, I don't really understand how I suppose to catch the right time of execution async?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <random>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

class RandomNum {
public:
    enum class Task {
        SMALL,
        BIG
    };
    Task task;

    RandomNum() {
        pickNum();
    }

    int randNum() {
        if (task == RandomNum::Task::SMALL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                rand();
            }
        }
        else if (task == RandomNum::Task::BIG) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
                rand();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

private:

    void pickNum() {
        int randNum = rand() % 100 + 1;
        task = (randNum % 2 == 0) ? RandomNum::Task::SMALL : RandomNum::Task::BIG;
    }

};

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    vector<RandomNum*> raNums;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        raNums.push_back(new RandomNum());
    }

    auto start = steady_clock::now();

    vector<future<int>> res;

    for (auto& value : raNums) {
        //if (value->task == RandomNum::Task::SMALL) {
        //  res.push_back(async(launch::deferred, &RandomNum::randNum, value));
        //}
        //else {
        //  res.push_back(async(launch::async, &RandomNum::randNum, value));
        //}
        res.push_back(async(launch::async, &RandomNum::randNum, value));
    }


    for (auto& i : res) {
        i.get();
    }

    auto stop = steady_clock::now();

    cout << "Time = " << duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start).count() << "ms.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "execution speed on the async policy"? Do you mean to measure how long each individual async task takes to execute?

Comment: @UnholySheep I need to measure how long it will take to complete the entire process. There are 100 objects in a vector `raNums` and each of them should randomize 10000000 numbers.

Comment: Isn't that what your code is doing right now? It's unclear to me what the problem is

Comment: @UnholySheep I've updated my code to the original version. I have 2 tasks here. In the first one, I need to use `deferred` for small numbers, and `async` for large numbers. Then just compare the time for all cases and find which way was faster. Now I get about the same time, but it seems to me that the `async` should be way faster since it does everything in parallel. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have:

- 15 seconds using both
- 18 seconds using `asynch` only
- 40 seconds using `deferred`only

It is very easy to understand that everything `deferred`is longer as a single thread does everything.

As my computer have 2 hyperthreaded cores, it make sense that `async`is roughly twice as fast.

Finally, by mixing both, it make sense that it is a bit faster as you avoid the overhead of `async`for small functions.

Having said that, you can probably guess a better a ratio (on a specific computer) by testing time with and without async using either only small or big  tasks so that so have a better idea of the improvement for a specific size.

In fact, it could be interesting to plot a graph for 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 and so on until 10000000. That way, you would have a much better understanding of the impact of the size and from which size, using tasks is useful.

As a reference, you might also want to compare time without using tasks at all by only generating random numbers...